# Estimating number of results from a MySQL "SELECT WHERE EXISTS" query?

Tags: mysql, innodb, query-performance

I have a simple database of "things" that can have zero or more "categories" or "tags" .  I've written a stored procedure that will get the first N objects in a given category, and performance is very good.  It looks something like

```
SELECT * FROM things
WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from thing_tags
    WHERE things.id = thing_tags.thing_id
      AND thing_tags.tag = @searchTag
  )
LIMIT ?
```

With a few hundred thousand "things", each having about 0-5 tags, performance is fine -- I can get the first couple hundred matches in tens of milliseconds at most.

However, if I want to know how many total matches there are, it takes ages -- many seconds, at least.  Is there a smarter way than just `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM .... (rest of query above)`?  The `id` field is indexed, per [this suggestion](http://www.cloudspace.com/blog/2009/08/06/fast-mysql-innodb-count-really-fast/), but the index doesn't help much since it has to inspect the `tags` table for each row in `things`.

I'm looking at implementing pagination, and I know `LIMIT ?,?` (or `LIMIT ? OFFSET ?`) would make it easy, but it would be nice to show the user an approximation at least of how many total "matches" to expect.

Comment: I think I'm just counting too damn many results.  I want the "results 1 - 20 of ######" to come back about as quickly as the actual results, but the total number is several orders of magnitude larger than the tiny subset I'm showing the user.  I don't think that simple performance tweaking / index building is going to get me there.  I think I need to estimate (maybe with representative sampling?) or else store the count elsewhere.  Does it change the game any if I say that the table only gets infrequent, sequential inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anybody with a similar problem, I wound up giving up -- I do a second query with a bigger (but still reasonable) limit, then render the result as "1-10 of 100+" (or whatever the bigger limit was).  This was good enough for my needs.

The short answer is that there is no good way to get a "pretty close" estimate for this kind of query, in this kind of database, without manually maintaining a separate count value somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the following should give a count

```
SELECT count(id) FROM things, things_tags
WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
  AND things.id=thing_tags.thing_id
  AND things_tags.tag = @searchTag
  GROUP BY things.id
```

With an index on things of (datestamp,id) and on thing_tags of (id,tag).
I have made the assumptions here that the tags for each thing are distinct.

Comment: This does give the exact count I want, it just takes two or three orders of magnitude longer than the LIMITed search :(

Answer (score 1):

from your comments I would draw you have a couple of option, all with pros and cons:

1. extensively improve your optimization. This includes indices and loading at least halve of the database into RAM. Trust me 300K row counts can be extremely fast. However RAM costs money and tweaking costs time.
2. do not represent a user a full 'next 1 to 926', but something like 'NEXT'. That is easy to implement as you just increase the limit by one but present your initial requested rows. If your database comes back with the +1 result you know, you must represent the NEXT
3. you can extent 2 by instead of limit 100 from the database you request for limit 300 and that way you can give the user +1 +2 +3 NEXT buttons
4. you denormalize your tables by creating a count table somewhere. Basicly that is what data wharehouses do. That gets ugly on the update mode, but works. I personally usually try to prevent such exercises because when I say 'ugly' I mean UGLY.
5. go for the explain and live with the fact that explain does not help with the lonely fruits. This is just about getting an idea about *10 *100 *1000 *10000 *100000.
6. combine these options, eg. 3 and 5, whereby the 5 pays into some nitty gritty graphical indicator and the 3 gives the user a hook to take action.
7. ask the 'does it make sense' question. This may become philosophical and I do not want to flame your ideas. However does a tag really make sense, that groups 300 K of items together? Is there any conceptional trade off you could go for?
8. Consider, if a little redesign is an option for you. I understood from previous conversations, that you store multiple (even 300K+) rows of the same tag string for the same thing in the table thing_tags. That means you have a denormalized string basket which sort of either shoots your indexing or your index memory utilization, which both cuts down your performance. Put the tag strings in a tag table and then have a 'bridge'/n:n table tag2thing with the only fields: tagid and thingid. Once done it makes sense to split the statements: 1. search for the ID of the tag and then 2. count on a join of  tag2things and your things table.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hi, I work at Cloudspace (we wrote the blog post you linked to).

One approach would be to alter your `things` table and add a `tags_count` column. Then, wherever you create or destroy `thing_tags`, you would add an update query to increment or decrement the appropriate `thing`.

This would allow you to select the count with something like

```
SELECT SUM(tags_count)
FROM things
WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
```

which should be faster and reasonably accurate.

I'm not sure what language/framework you're working with, but on the off-chance that you're using Ruby on Rails, Rails has support for this [built in](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast) (called counter_cache).

---

**EDIT:** I just realized that you're also limiting by the `@searchTag`, so I'm not sure how helpful my suggestion above will be in that case.

Perhaps you could do something like this? This counts the `thing_tags` matching `@searchTag` and having a `thing` between `@start` and `@end`.

```
SELECT count(thing_tags.id)
FROM thing_tags
  INNER JOIN things
    ON thing_tags.thing_id = things.id
WHERE things.datestamp > @start
  AND things.datestamp < @end
  AND thing_tags.tag = @searchTag
```

Answer (score 0):

the explain statement gives an indication on counts which is not exact, but very fast

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

so try something like this:

```
explain SELECT * FROM things,thing_tags
WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
  AND   things.id = thing_tags.thing_id AND thing_tags.tag = @searchTag
```

another update:
This work bestif you have an index id,datestamp on things and an index tag on things.tag

Strong optimization may be achieved if you separate the queries (pseudo code php+mysql)
into:

```
1. thingids=implode(',',Select thing_id from thing_tags where thing_tags.tag = @searchTag)
2a. explain SELECT * FROM things WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
      AND   things.id in (@thingids)

2b. SELECT count(*) FROM things WHERE things.datestamp > @start AND things.datestamp < @end
      AND   things.id in (@thingids)
```

2a and 2b can be run alternately.

Usually innodb operations on strings are tricky. So this might be your perfomance hook, which may foster the statement separation.

Optimized solution depends on your set up - so room for testing.

Comment: Explain is very fast but doesn't actually give even an estimate of the final result.  It shows a row count for `thing_tags` but that's more than 3x the actual, correct result from my query.

Comment: I guess, you need to work on your indeces´; can you post the explains?

Comment: I don't think your `implode` is going work out; for some common tag values the query would number into the hundreds of thousands.  That's the crux of the problem -- I'm selecting the first, say, hundred out of 300k records, but counting that 300k takes ten seconds while the actual results come back in 10ms...

Comment: have you ever considered something like this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/? - "innodb_buffer_pool_size 70-80% of memory is a safe bet. I set it to 12G on 16GB box." I go this route and usually have no worries with counting 300K - probably statement separation is not really necessary.